# Active jobs count in Quartz.Net

Tags: quartz.net, quartz

We have a wcf service (hosted in windows service) that does some processing which can take several minutes to complete (1 to 5 min or sometimes more)
We need to poll a database periodically (every 2 min) to fetch the items to be processed and call this service for each item. I’m thinking of using Quartz.Net for this use case.

Create a quartz job that will run every 2 min and get the items to be processed from DB.
For each record, create a job and schedule the job to be executed immediately.
We want to limit the maximum number of concurrent processing (say, 100 max) to avoid memory issues.
To do this, one of the options is to get only as much records from DB as that can be processed
ie if 60 jobs are currently executing, we need to get only 40 records from DB.
This requires us to know how many jobs are currently executing before getting items from DB.

When the first job fires to get the records from DB, is it possible to know how many processes are currently executing? 
There’s a method **IScheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs** which I think can be used to get the count of active jobs.
The processing service is a one-way method, how will Quartz know if the processing is still active or completed?

Comment: This is not for what Quartz is for. Quartz is a scheduler for recurring jobs, not for one time firing. Of course, you can schedule jobs that run only one time and delete themself after execution. But there are better methods to achieve that. You can try [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) or use a [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) or you can use a `SemaphoreSlim`. And plenty of other ways to achieve that.

Comment: You can register each of your N jobs every time you create this instant processing job and then unregister it after job complete it's job. Your main job which will create jobs will need to checks how many jobs gets registered in your persistent place.